# How to calculate RunningValue % in SSRS using expressions

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to calculate YTD% which is shown below:

[image: screenshot]

the calculation goes like (90+77)/(90+68)

```
                      (90+70+68)/(90+68+68)
```

My tablix dataset gets two values sum(Amt1) and sum(Amt2) which are calculated by the Tablix for every FiscalQuarter i.e Grouped by Quarter.

The tablix has a RowGroup which is grouped on: FiscalQuarter. So to calculate YTD %

I did this

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Amt1.Value,sum)/RunningValue(Fields!Amt2.Value,sum)
```

which didn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the scope of the source within the expression:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Amt1.Value, Sum, "DataSet1") / RunningValue(Fields!Amt2.Value, Sum, "DataSet1")
```